# CakePHP cookie not being decoded

Tags: php, cakephp, cookies

I'm storing a basket in a cookie. Getting the array on our development server works fine:

```
$this->Cookie->read('basket')
```

```
Array
(
    [products] => Array
        (
            [15912] => Array
                (
                    [amount] => 4
                )

        )

    [custom] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Getting the cookie on our live server, on the other hand, returns a JSON string.

```
{\"products\":{\"15622\":{\"amount\":1}},\"custom\":[]}
```

Is there some simple PHP server setting that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I almost couldn't believe it but: Magic quotes was on.

(Last time I worked on a server with magic quotes enabled was 2006, I believe.)